# multiple actions from javascript if

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I can't seem to find the documentation that discusses this, so I thought maybe someone on here could help. I want to write a javascript if/else function that triggers multiple events. My code is a little rough, but I think it should look like:

```js
function getFruit() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myinput").value;
  var score;
  var picture;

  if (x === "Apple") {
    score = "A" || pciture = "http://exampple.com/assets/apple.jpg";
    else(x === "Banana") {
      score = "B" || picture = "http://example.com/assets/banana.jpg";
    }
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = score;
    document.getElementById("display").image.src = picture;
  }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myinput">
<p id="text"></p>
<img id="display"></img>
```

Comment: Within the If (or else) block you can just declare the new actions on multiple lines ... as long as it lives within curly brackets.  The double pipe symbols, in JS, represents an OR statement, not a new line.

Comment: Explain what your code is supposed to do, and what the “events” you are talking about are.

Comment: You really need to start from the beginning again and follow some basic tutorials

Comment: The || in your if and else block shouldn't be there plus you have a typo in the if pciture vs picture. You need to define those variables on a different line

Comment: Why do you have an OR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need them on different lines. There is no reason for doing the `||`.

```
function getFruit() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myinput").value;
    var score;
    var picture;

    if (x === "Apple") {
       score = "A";
       picture = "http://exampple.com/assets/apple.jpg";
    }
    else if (x === "Banana") {
       score = "B";
       picture = "http://example.com/assets/banana.jpg";
    }
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = score;
    document.getElementById("display").image.src = picture;
}
```

Comment: I shouldn't have assumed that they knew how to do that.

Comment: `else if` does not seem a valid `else` in javscript

Comment: based on their original code they are trying to do an `else if` rather than an `else`

Comment: Thanks for the correction on multiple line entries. And you are correct, my syntax is for else if not else...my bad

Answer (score 0):

Multiple errors of syntaxis in your code.

This is a correct if/else statement

```
    if (x === "Apple") {
       ...
    } else {
       ...
    }
```

```js
function getFruit() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myinput").value;
  var score;
  var picture;

  if (x === "Apple") {
    score = "A";
    picture = "http://exampple.com/assets/apple.jpg";
  } else {
    score = "B";
    picture = "http://example.com/assets/banana.jpg";
  }
  
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = score;
  document.getElementById("display").src = picture;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myinput">
<p id="text"></p>
<img id="display" src="">
<button onclick="getFruit()">Check</button>
```

Comment: should be `else if` because they want to check if `x === "Banana"`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a cleaner code, and avoid to have the same variable assignment all over the place you should wrap everything in an Object and use the input's value to access the properties

```js
// Call this function differently renderFruit, or loadFruit, etc
function getFruit() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myinput").value;
  var fruits = {
    Apple: {
      score: 'A',
      picture: 'https://via.placeholder.com/300x120?text=Apple'
    },
    Banana: {
      score: 'B',
      picture: 'https://via.placeholder.com/300x120?text=Banana'
    }
  };
  var f = fruits[x];
  document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = f && f.score;
  document.getElementById("display").src = f && f.picture;

  // Please don't name getSomething to a function that does not
  // have a return statement e.g.: return f;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myinput" onchange="getFruit()">
<p id="text"></p>
<img id="display" />
```

Comment: This is a really interesting code block, and I'll test it out. Thanks for posting this!